# Android Timestamp overflow

Tags: android, timestamp, long-integer

```
public static final long ONE_MONTH_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
public static final long THREE_MONTHS_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90;
```

These 2 lines give me this warning :

> Numeric overflow in expression

Rightfully indeed considering a long can reach 2,147,483,647 max and one month in milliseconds already reach 2,592,000,000

I was wondering how to avoid the overflow (beside converting it in seconds).

On a side note, how is :

```
long currentDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Even working ? I mean milliseconds since epoch are much greater than 3 months, so how is it succssfully stored into a long ?

Comment: 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) is the maximum value of an `int`. The maximum value of a `long` is actually 9223372036854775807 (2^63 - 1). And if you make these primitives unsigned the maximum positive values double again. See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public static final long ONE_MONTH_INTERVAL = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 30L;
public static final long THREE_MONTHS_INTERVAL = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L* 90L;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem ! Could you though give a bit more explanations ?

Comment: Multiplying like you mentioned is integer multiplication not long. So by defining L at the end of each number fixes that.

Comment: Also for max value check Long class MAX_VALUE attribute.